# Run function IF :has :not class

Tags: jquery

I only want this function to run if `.toolbar li` does not have the class .Oactive:

```
$(".prod_description").mousedown(function(){
$(this).parent().parent().addClass('mousedown');
$(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass('mousedown'); 
})
.mouseup(function(){
$(this).parent().parent().removeClass('mousedown');
$(this).parent().parent().parent().removeClass('mousedown');
});
```

What do I need to wrap this in to ensure this?

```
something like: if $(.toolbar li):not(:has .Oactive) {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if($("ul.toolbar li:not(.oActive)")){`

You should always specify the element type (ul in this case) when possible when using classes - it speeds up the selector engine.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($('.toolbar li').hasClass('Oactive'))
{
    // do cool stuff
}
```